# Java method for type safe return generic subclass

Tags: java, generics, subclass

I'm using the following code to get the first matching element with the given class (Dog, Cat) from a list of abstract type (Animal). Is there another type safe way to do it?

```
// get the first matching animal from a list
public <T extends Animal>T get(Class<T> type) {
    // get the animals somehow
    List<Animal> animals = getList();
    for(Animal animal : animals) {
        if(type.isInstance(animal)) {
            // this casting is safe
            return (T)animal;
        }
    }
    // if not found
    return null;
}

// both Cat and Dog extends Animal
public void test() {
    Dog dog = get(Dog.class); // ok
    Cat cat = get(Dog.class); // ok, expected compiler error
}
```

(Cat and Dog extends Animal)

Comment: What is the `job` variable?

Comment: You're right, the second line should not compile, assuming `Dog` doesn't extend `Cat`.

Comment: just updated the job, sorry about that

Comment: @Fallup: oh, come on, type is an object, you can't do that!

Comment: I do get a compilation error when trying your code snippet: *Type mismatch: cannot convert from Dog to Cat*

Comment: Indeed, here is proof of the compilation error: http://ideone.com/fbaLEL.

Comment: @sp00m compiler error is expected, right?

Comment: @OnurGunduru Yes, it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change one thing in your code. Instead of

```
return (T)animal;
```

I would use

```
return type.cast(animal);
```

The latter will not generate unchecked cast warning.

Comment: this is actually helpful, i'll upvote when i have enough rep.

Answer (score 3):

The code looks correct. This line:

```
Cat cat = get(Dog.class);
```

[Indeed should not compile.](http://ideone.com/gqzkkf)

I would make sure you're not using rawtypes anywhere in your code, as often this will "opt out" of generics for seemingly unrelated code.

Comment: Even if raw types are provided is it neccessary to include additional controls?

Comment: @OnurGunduru I don't understand your comment. You should avoid using raw types. As it is, your example is correct and the premise that the second call to `get` compiles is false.

Comment: Thats ok, i am basically looking if there is any other way to do it. I'm not into generics that much, after a lot of reading this is what i came up with. Sorry if my comment wasn't clear: if animal was a raw type (probably leading to a compiler warning) do i need to include any additional controls in the if block

Comment: @OnurGunduru `Animal` *can't* be a raw type unless it declares any type parameters, like `class Animal<T>` and then you still used plain `Animal`. What's generic in your example is the method `get`, which declares a type parameter `T extends Animal`.

Comment: @OnurGunduru If there's anything I'm missing you should update the question to reflect it - as it is it's a very confusing question because claims something that's not true. Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @PaulBelora "claims something that's not true" compiler error is not a problem. I pasted the code to be clear about it. At the end i'm looking for an alternate way to get an object from a list of objects sharing the same base class.

Comment: by the way how long should wait to close/accept questions on SO?

Answer (score 3):

I get compiler error with your code:

```
public void test() {
    Dog dog = get(Dog.class); // ok
    Cat cat = get(Dog.class); // compiler error
}
```

and I can see only one case when it may compile:

```
class Dog extends Cat {
}
```

Comment: compiler error is expected, it should also not compile when Dog extends Cat

Comment: if Dog is a Cat (extends Cat), then it will compile, this is OOP